# Making text pulsate in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, animation, swiftui

So I am trying to make some text fade in and out to give a pulsate type effect, this is the code I have now:

```
struct SignInView: View {
    @State private var opacity: Double = 0.0
    @State private var pulseDown: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .center) {
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                AppDelegate.signInWithGoogle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign In")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .opacity(opacity)
            })
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear {
            self.pulsateText()
        }
    }
    
    private func pulsateText() {
        DispatchQueue.init(label: "Pulse").asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.01) {
            if self.pulseDown {
                self.opacity -= 0.02
            } else {
                self.opacity += 0.02
            }
            
            if self.opacity > 1 {
                self.pulseDown = true
            } else if self.opacity < 0.1 {
                self.pulseDown = false
            }
            
            self.pulsateText()
        }
    }
}
```

It does exactly what I want and looks good, but I can't help but feel that an infinite recursive loop is not the right way to be doing it. I suppose I could make an infinite while instead of the infinite recursion, though that still seem not ideal. Is there a better way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is an easier more SwiftUI-like way. It works by using an [`Animation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animation)'s [`repeatForever(autoreverses:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/animation/repeatforever(autoreverses:)) method:

```
struct SignInView: View {

    @State private var visible = true
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Spacer()
            
            Button(action: {
                print("Sign in with Google")
//                AppDelegate.signInWithGoogle()
            }, label: {
                Text("Sign In")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                    .opacity(visible ? 1 : 0)
            })
            
            Spacer()
        }
        .padding()
        .onAppear(perform: pulsateText)
    }
    
    private func pulsateText() {
        withAnimation(Animation.easeInOut.repeatForever(autoreverses: true)) {
            visible.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for, thanks! Is there an easy way to slow it down? Edit: Figured it out, just need to pass a duration parameter to `easeInOut` thanks again!

Comment: It seems that after the latest Xcode update it not longer works - now the entire view slides from the top left corner to the middle of the screen and back on loop, any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @Quinn It still works for me, so you must have changed something since (such as adding an animation to whatever other views are in the VStack).

Comment: nope, just updated Xcode - it still works if I build it on my old computer with the exact same code - running it on my newer computer with a newer version of Xcode gives me crazy results